# Angular flex-layout in Ionic3... rxjs/operator not found?

Tags: npm, ionic2, ionic3, angular-flex-layout

Trying to use @angular/flex-layout in an existing npm-enabled Ionic 3 project.

Adding "FlexLayoutModule" to my main module's imports won't allow the app to start, saying that: `cannot find module "rxjs/operators"` is the cause.

Already cleared node_module, npm install, reinstalled Ionic CLI. Nothing helps. Could it be a version conflict? Moreover, I'm already using Observables in this project. I don't get it. And the import of "FlexLayoutModule" is in cause of this issue (disabling the import removes the issue).

Anyone could be successful at using flex-layout with ionic? I've seen this plunk, but it uses system.js, so not 100% reproducing my goal.

http://plnkr.co/edit/y8R0MF?p=info

**Edit:** a more verbose issue:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators"
>   Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators" at Object.580
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/22.main.js:319:7) at **webpack_require**
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:48:30) at Object.1021
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/22.main.js:11:79) at **webpack_require**
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:48:30) at
>   http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:122015:10 at t.invoke
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9283) at Object.onInvoke
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4650:37) at t.invoke
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9223) at r.run
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4452) at
>   http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14076

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting a similar error with Angular CLI. Everything is OK until I include FlexLayoutModule in the app's NgModule imports. Then I get the error:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operators' in 'D:\dev\Vms.Signup.Client\node_modules\@angular\flex-layout\esm5'

I updated to the latest rxjs and that seems to have fixed it.